# Python import from beyond top-level package

Tags: python, django

I am developing a Django project for which I wrote some non-web related libraries.

My directory structure looks something like this:

Main folder

- Theorem prover

  - **here are the things I want to import**
- web

  - app

    - **here's where I want to import things from**

The place where I'm running the app is the `web/` folder. What would be the proper way of doing this?

Comment: You could write a `setup.py` so you can *install* the theorem prover package.

Comment: use virtualenv and follow what jonrsharpe says 1 cm above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Theorem prover folder to your `PYTHONPATH`. Either setting the environment variable prior to app launch, or by

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/theorem')
```

Before importing the theorem related modules.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure, that your settings.py which located at the project root directory, has `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`
- from web -> app -> here's where I want to import things from:
  `import Theorem_prover.here_are_the_things_I_want_to_import`

Answer (score 1):

Use [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html).

```
importlib.import_module(name, package=None)
```

> Import a module. The name argument specifies what module to import in absolute or relative terms (e.g. either `pkg.mod` or `..mod`). If the name is specified in relative terms, then the package argument must be set to the name of the package which is to act as the anchor for resolving the package name (e.g. `import_module('..mod', 'pkg.subpkg')` will import pkg.mod).